# Create a pointer of type 'this' / current object

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, c++11, typeid

Is there a way to create a pointer of the current object type using the 'this' keyword or similar, so that the class type is not mentioned explicitly?

I have a base class GraphicObjects which can act as a container for other GraphicObjects and objects derived from GraphicObjects. I thought this may have been better than explicitly naming the type in the class so I can use it elsewhere / change the class names.

```
class GraphiObjects {
  typeid(*this) *a; // Fails.
  GraphicObjects *b; // This works.
  GraphicObjects *children_[];
};
```

If it is possible, are there any reasons not to use this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? `typeid` returns a `std::type_info` *object*. Did you confuse it with C++11's [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)? Stuff like `typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type a;` is perfectly valid in *methods*, but ... well ...

Comment: Templates are probably able to save you, but why is it not just possible to write `Alpha*`? If it's just a matter or preference, then I'd say "it's part of the language, don't hack around it".

Comment: @Michael I have a base class GraphicObjects which can act as a container for other GraphicObjects and objects derived from GraphicObjects. I thought this may have been better than explicitly naming the type in the class so I can use it elsewhere / change the class names .

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question with the *actual* situation you are considering.

Comment: @dhke Yep, I confused it with decltype (not come across this before). Thanks

Comment: @MicroVirus Good point. Edited

Comment: I still don't see the point. If you're changing the class name of `GraphicsObject`, then you're going to have to change all the code that uses it... changing the type of one member variable along with the class name seems very insignificant compared to the other code changes in all the different files.

Comment: If the most specific type is `GraphicsObject`, explicitly name it. If the type of the contained object might evolve in the future (e.g. a split between `ChildGraphicsObject` and `RootGraphicsObject`), you might consider the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Or simple use a typedef somewhere.

Comment: So what type do you want? `GraphicObjects`, or an unknown type derived from `GraphicObjects` which happens to be the *dynamic* type of `*this`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wasn't sure if it was the done thing (lots to learn). I will just name the type.

Comment: @n.m.The current class type, not further derived classes. Does _this_ keep the type of the derived object if it has been upcast?

Comment: Yes, if it has virtual functions, then `typeid` will refer to the most derived type.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a compiled language with a mostly static type system. In particular, every expression has a type which is determined at compile time. For instance, in functions of `GraphiObjects` the `this` pointer has type `GraphiObjects*`, possibly with `const` and/or `volatile` added.

Now there is also such a thing as a "runtime type", because C++ is an OO language. Because `this` is a `GraphiObjects*` pointer, it can point to a `GraphiObjects` object but also to an object of a derived class. `typeid` supports runtime queries, but you're trying to use it at compile time.

You can use `decltype(*this)` with member functions, but you can't use it for member data. This makes sense: `const` methods have a const-qualified `this`  pointer, non-const methods don't, but for a data member there's no way to determine if `this` should be const-qualified.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: C++ isn't "an OO language" (although that's one paradigm it supports), and that doesn't mean it has no runtime types.  Python is an OO language and has runtime types, so I'm not sure what you're trying to say in your second paragraph.

Comment: @TobySpeight: In C++ speak, "dynamic type" doesn't mean that types are created at runtime. It's used specifically in contexts where an expression refers to an object, and the type of the object doesn't match the type of the expression. In this case, the type of the expression is referred to as the static type, and the type of the object as the dynamic type, and the former usually is a base class of the latter (ignoring `void*`). This is related to C++'s `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @MSalters - sorry, I think I misread "such a thing" as "no such thing", and completely missed what you meant.  Re-reading it now, it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

## Is there a way to create a pointer of the current object type?

Yes, [`this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this). Creating a member variable that replicates `this` is wasteful at best.

## I have a base `class GraphicObjects` which can act as a container for other `GraphicObjects` and objects derived from `GraphicObjects`

Please don't do this. Create your object hierarchy and use a standard container to contain them. Otherwise every one of your objects, even the non-base objects contain an empty `children_` member, as well as any other members and functionality necessary to manipulate it. This is wasteful and confusing.

## I thought this may have been better than explicitly naming the type in the class so I can use it elsewhere / change the class names.

Because you are using classes that are all in `GraphicObjects`' hierarchy, you should take advantage of [polymorphisim](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/). You can refer to all the objects in this hierarchy with a `GraphicObjects*` And retrieving the object type is as simple as doing a [`dynamic_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/#dynamic_cast).

I've written a rather extensive example to demonstrate the use of polymorphisim with a container here: http://ideone.com/XSjMHW

**EDIT:**

1. Not all your objects will contain other objects, these node objects which won't contain anything should be of one type, we'll call it `class Node`, *which does not contain other objects*
2. Other objects may have their own expression, but also contain other objects, these should be of a separate type, we'll call it `class Container`, `Container` may either inherit from `Node` or have a member `Node`, it will also contain other `Node`s/`Container`s

Comment: Thanks for the information and example. I meant a pointer **of** the current type rather than **to** the current object. A bit beyond the scope of my original question, but I have a Text graphic object which inherits from GraphicObject. I then have a button object which contains a Text object as well as it's own drawing code for the button face. Then a Screen/Form object which could contain zero or more Graphic  objects. Would you keep GraphicObject without a container and just have a container in each of the derived objects? I was thinking of a very cut down version of the .NET Control class

Comment: @mattb5906 I've edited to try to clarify an objective way to setup the class structure which you depict. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: That's great. Thank you for that.